# Estimating number of occurrences of binomial tests

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, error

I have data representing a counting of the number of successes in a series of $n$-trial binomial experiments, however each experiment might have a different $n$ and is unknown.

So, if I for example have counted 10 experiments where the number of successes was $k=3$, it might be from 6 experiments with $n=3$ and 4 experiments of $n=4$ with one failed trial.

An example for my counts would be `{1: 100, 2: 50, 3: 450, ...}`

I do not have data regarding $k=0$, as I am not aware an experiment ever took place.

There is a maximum possible $n$ which I know, $N$, and I also know the success probability $p$.

I need to estimate the number of $n$-trial experiments for each $n$.

Let us use $n'_k$ for the measured number of experiments with $k$ successes and $n_k$ for the real count.

I started by writing down the expected relation between the two:

$$
n'_k = \sum_i binom(k, i, p) \cdot n_i
$$

With $i$ going from $k$ to $N$.

In other words - experiments with $n>k$ may have contributed to the count of experiments with $k$ successes.

This formula is easily reversed, and allows straightforward calculations when applied from $k=N$ to lower $k$'s.

When I apply these formulae to simulated data, I get large errors - so large that only at extremely large samples the results are usable.

So, I have a few questions...

1. I'm guessing I'm not inventing the wheel -- is there a name to the problem I'm describing?
2. Is there a different/better method I may go by?
3. Am I getting the maximum likelihood with my method?
4. How do I estimate the expected error for this model?

Comment: I don't follow the description of your data entirely, but when you say you *know* $p$ can you not just recover $n$ as $k/p$? Alternatively, the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) which models the number of trials (or the number of failures $n-k$) until a certain amount of successes is observed might be useful.

Comment: I understand my explanation was a bit wordy... The main point is that I don't know what n is for each experiment, I only know the number of successes in each experiment. So if there was an experiment with n=5;k=2 and another with n=3;k=2 they would be under the same "bin". I need to estimate the number of experiments with n trials (successful and failed ones) for each n.